# prove that inf $f\geq 0$ if and only if $ae^{1+b}\geq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, supremum-and-infimum

Ive got a function $f(x)=a+bx+xlnx$ for all $x\in(0,\infty)$ and I need to prove that inf $f\geq 0$ if and only if $ae^{1+b}\geq 1$.

I have already proved that $f$ is convex and have found a formula for inf, inf $f=$max$\{b\in \mathbb{R}: v\leq x$ for all $x\in f\}$ but I am unsure how to implement the question to show what is required. Any help will be great.

Comment: In "inf $f=$max$\{b\in \mathbb{R}: v\leq x$ for all $x\in f\}$", what is $v$, and what does $x\in f$ mean?

Comment: The definition you found of $\inf f$ applies when $f$ is an ordered set (e.g. a subset of $\Bbb{R}$), not when $f$ is a function. You could interpret $\inf f$ as $\inf \{f(x) : x \in (0, \infty)\}$, but I think you should just interpret it as the greatest lower bound for all function values of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

We want $(b+\ln x)x\geq -a$ for all $x >0$  which means  $\inf \{(b+\ln x)x: x>0\} \geq -a$. By differentiation we see that the infimum is attained at $x=e^{-1-b}$. [The function is decreasing up to this point and increasing after that]. Thus the condition  we need is $(b+(-1-b)) e^{-1-b} \geq -a$ which says $ae^{1+b } \geq 1$.

Comment: Yeah. And I realised it has to be moved anyways at the end. But I do think it makes things a little less opaque if you keep the original $\geq0$ explicitly visible.